# Python Unique Lines in File and Line Breaking

Tags: python, file, parsing, unique

I'm working on creating a log parser based on a command line style script that prints out the match. The idea is to output only unique lines in the log that match a few unique values. An example format of what is being uniquely pulled is below.

```
From source books, query: ((domain:www.users.com || username:ed || location:boston || years:2 || title:lead || last_update:{2019-09-19T16:44:36.153Z TO 2019-09-19T16:48:04.125Z] && userid_17:*).
From source books, query: ((domain:www.users.com || username:john || location:austin || years:1 || title:associate || last_update:{2019-09-19T16:44:40.133Z TO 2019-09-19T16:48:06.145Z] && userid_18:*).
```

Among other lines, these lines are unique in that they have the userid_, domain and years. If those 3 are not in the line, they don't need to be displayed.

A new line will be written to the log every 10 min with an updated last_update timestamp. I only need the first hit for that userid. In my script, I have removed the timestamp between the { ] effectively making the lines all the same to make it easier to pull the unique line.

Currently my script is "working" however I'm sure this can be cleaned up and hoping for ideas. I'm still very new at Python scripting so critic away. Right now the line break is not working and I feel that would make this visually easier to see.

I also feel userid_ would be better for unique, however wasn't sure how to say find this unique value once, but also has to have search 2 and 3.

Criteria:

- Unique output, there should only be one userid_ line printed per id
- domain and years are unique to this search, other lines that include
  userid_ without those two matches do not need to be printed
- Must have a line break after each unique find to make reading easier.

Note: this is a tool with other command line arguments. This is false data, there are many more items within this string of the live data, but truncating to hopefully make it easier to understand the request.

```
import os, sys, argparse, urllib.parse, csv, re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Choose an option')

# Setup required arguments
parser.add_argument('-b', action="store_true", help='searches users with domain and years')
args = parser.parse_args()

#Get Current Working Directory
dirpath = os.getcwd()

if args.b:
        debug_log = dirpath+'/var/log/database/debug.log'
        # 3 items are unique to this line vs other similar "userid_" lines 
        search1="userid_"
        search2="domain"
        search3="years"
        with open(debug_log, 'r') as search:
                unique = set()
                for lines in search:
                        #search the file for matching terms
                        if search1 and search2 and search3 in lines:
                                #remove the last_update items, anything between { and ] to make it unique
                                removed = re.sub(r'\{(.*?)\]', '', lines)
                                if removed not in unique:
                                        unique.add(removed)
                print(unique)
```

The output of this script comes out like below, so it does work. However the line break does not even though there is a \n in the output. I'm assuming because set is being used? When there are 50+ hits the single line output is harder to read.

```
{'From source books, query: ((domain:www.users.com || username:ed || location:boston || years:2 || title:lead || last_update: && userid_17:*).\n', 'From source books, query: ((domain:www.users.com || username:john || location:austin || years:1 || title:associate || last_update: && userid_18:*).\n'}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than printing the stringification of the `unique` set, you want to print out each line that is in the set.

That is, change

```
print(unique)
```

to

```
for line in unique:
    print(line, end='')
```

(That'll work in Python 3, which it looks like you're using.)

(The `end=''` is there because each `line` ends with a newline, and by default, `print` also appends a newline. You don't want both.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, and does not really address the "why", but if you just need to get on with your life, can you try adding your own '\n' as in:

```
if removed not in unique:
     unique.add(removed + '\n')
```

Unfortunately, that's the way *I* work :/

Comment: hmm. So I did try something like that. Gave it another shot and it oddly just adds another \n to the output.
```{'From source books, query: ((domain:www.users.com || username:john || location:austin || years:1 || title:associate || last_update: && userid_18:*).\n\n', 'From source books, query: ((domain:www.users.com || username:ed || location:boston || years:2 || title:lead || last_update: && userid_17:*).\n\n'}```

Comment: I'm thinking your use of Set() and 'not in' is redundant, as a Set won't have duplicates.  I'm not really familiar with Set but if you replace it with a list maybe it will work better.  As in:  instead of 'unique = Set()' use 'unique = []', and then instead of unique.add use unique.append (keeping the if.. not in... logic).

Comment: Can you edit your question to include 3-4 lines of your log file?

Comment: Another idea would be to replace print(unique) with print(str(unique)) when using the set.